# Are there any words without a meaning?

Tags: meaning, philosophy

From Geoffrey Hunter's Metalogic, p.5:

> ... a thing is an English word only if it has meaning.

It got me thinking: is this really so? **Is it possible for there to be an English word that is absolutely void of meaning, i.e. meaningless?**

Can I not come up with a word on my own, and not give it any meaning whatsoever? Do made-up words enter the "gates of English" if and only if they have meaning?

**P.S.** I don't know if this question is more suitable for Linguistics.SE (or, perhaps, Philosophy.SE under the 'philosophy_of_language' tag?), since I am interested in an answer for natural languages in general as well. I have focused on English probably because the book I'm reading is in English, the statement was made by a native speaker of English, and English is the language I am most familiar with.

Comment: Can you show us a couple of more sentences before and after the quote? I don't think it is a question related with English Language and Usage. It rather reads like a request for interpretation.

Comment: Pay no attention. This is a philosopher speculating about language without any clear idea of how it works. Clearly he subscribes to the Conduit Metaphor and doesn't distinguish language from thought; English words don't "have meaning", to begin with. And many English words -- for instance _the_ and _a_ -- cannot be said to "have" any meaning at all.

Comment: John Lawler nailed it as usual. I am grateful for his participation.

Comment: Let's think about acronyms.  Is there really a difference between NASA and SANA (an acronym I just invented but which is probably used for something, somewhere)?  Can we say that one is a word and the other isn't?  That seems illogical to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do made-up words enter the "gates of English" if and only if they have meaning?

No.

Nonsense words exist, put to good effect in Lewis Carroll’s [“Jabberwocky”](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/42916):

> ’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
>        Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
>   All mimsy were the borogoves,
>        And the mome raths outgrabe.

Etc.

They are words, but they mean nothing. And the sum of them make a delightful nonsense poem.

Furthermore, in linguistics, there are many words that linguists deem mean nothing.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time writing this wonderful answer!

Comment: One could argue that they do have meaning, but that it's very subjective:  in other words, many readers will invent their own meaning for "brillig" or "slithy" on reading, in order to create a mental picture.  Perhaps they would imagine that "slithy" has a meaning similar to "slimy", or "slithering",  for example.

Comment: @MaxWilliams in the case of this poem, every reader's vague attached "meaning" formed via extremely vague mental images can hardly be called meaning.

Comment: @MichaelSmith this is probably getting too philosophical, but I disagree.  **all** meaning is subjective.  The world only exists for us inside our minds, as a perception.  We can talk about objective reality for convenience sake, but it's all subjective really.  A word can mean different things to different people.  Who are you to say that someone's perception isn't valid?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I would argue that the meaning of, say (among the other words Lewis came up with), _brillig_ is entirely under control of the person who came up with the word, i.e., Lewis Carroll. If he didn't impose any sort of meaning on this word (and I am pretty positive that this is so), then the word really does not have any meaning. This whole discussion at this point brings us back to my original question: is coming up with a word and not attaching any meaning to it make it a legitimate word of the English language? So we're back where we started.

Comment: Well, "brillig" is definitely a word.  If it's not a word, then what is it?  A string of characters?  Let's say that it's a word.  Carroll may have had something in mind for the meaning but he didn't share it, so let's say that it has no **definition**.  However, if I hear it and imagine something as a result, then I'd say that it **means** that thing that I pictured.  That's my subjective interpretation of it's meaning.  It will be different from yours, or someone else's.  But to say that that **is not a meaning** seems wrong to me.

Comment: We can legitimately say *"What does the word "summer" mean to you?"*  for example, meaning "What thoughts or memories does the word summer evoke for you?".  Inherent in this question is the idea that a word means different things to different people, ie has a different subjective meaning for each person.

Comment: Although, we can differentiate between "words" and "English words", the latter being "words that have a definition in the dictionary" perhaps, and this may have been your point.  Brillig is clearly a word but not an *English* word.  Apologies if I've completely missed the mark with my philosophical musings.

Comment: I'm afraid that the word _meaning_ means two different things here. If we're talking about a word learned ostensively, its meanings (no pun intended) is the one you're talking about. If we're talking about a word that is completely new in its composition and has been made up by a human being intentionally, the word _meaning_ has the meaning I'm talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43086/discussion-between-michael-smith-and-max-williams).

Comment: Carroll's nonsense words, I would argue, have not entered the "gates of English". They may be words, but English they are not. At that point, what separates a "word" from "any collection of letters or sounds"?

Comment: @NuclearWang - Do you know how many people know that poem by heart? Or know likes of that poem? Millions of people. When millions of people can pit nonsense words into context, they have, indeed, entered the "gates of English."

Answer (score -1):

Every word at some point had no meaning until the persons who used it gave it meaning. For example "on fleek" was an expression that took over the internet a few years ago and had no meaning until the word was validated by millions of people. This is how language is created.

Comment: You will want to cite the sources for the information supplied. Otherwise  there is nothing but opinion..

Comment: I'd never heard of 'on fleek'. Googled, it has a presence; but I would not say that it has caught on.